# Rails elastic Beanstalk cannot deploy -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Error says `cannot allocate memory` but lots of googling has shown native gems are troubling on beanstalk.

```
 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

      /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/bin/ruby extconf.rb
  Cannot allocate memory - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/bin/ruby extconf.rb 2>&1

  Gem files will remain installed in /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
  Results logged to /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
```

is there a way to verify beanstalk can install this gem without problems?

Answer (score 1):

Did you attempt locally package the gems in Beanstalk? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/locally-packaging-gem-dependencies-for-ruby-applications-in-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: no local packaging is not mentioned in any of the official documentation. would prefer to let the build system package all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Letting the build system package all the dependencies take up more resources than the default EC2 instance can handle.

Increase the size of your EC2 instance/ Swapfile during ElasticBeanstalk deployment to fix this issue.

check my previous response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42575594/4372872)