# Degraded Health in Elastic beanstalk - can't figure out the cause

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two `r5a.xlarge` ec2 instances in my environment. Each instance has 4 vCPU and 32 GiB Memory
The application processes some files are returns the data in json to the client. Two of the files it processes are also quite large (about 1.5GB). I don't have db connection. The application is using Python 3.6 with `flask` and running on an `apache` server

The instances are going in to "degraded" state after a few incoming requests.
The causes shown are:

> 25.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx. Instance ELB health state has been "OutOfService" for 1 hour 23 minutes: Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively. 99 % of CPU is in use. 96 % in I/O wait. 100 % ofmemory is in use.

despite stopping the incoming requests, it stayed in this state.

The other instance for some reason has an incorrect version deployed.

> Incorrect application version "app-xxxxxxx" (deployment 24). Expected version "app-yyyyyy" (deployment 23).

I set my load balancer capacity to 0. This removed both instances. I redeployed the application and then set the capacity back to the original setting which was Min = 1, Max = 2, Desired = 2

I did this so that it has new instances with the correct code base version.

Its now with running with 1 instance and after 7-8+ requests it has gone in to degraded state again.
The cause again is

> 100 % of memory is in use.

I have tried creating swap space as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274825/deployment-to-elastic-beanstalk-fails-with-cannot-allocate-memory-error)

I even checked the `httpd_error` log and could not find any error relating to this. This is the full error from the `httpd_error` file

```
[suexec:notice] [pid 2880] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[http2:warn] [pid 2880] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[http2:warn] [pid 2880] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2880] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[:warn] [pid 2880] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[:warn] [pid 2880] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.12.
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2880] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

How do I even begin to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the application. I had to make some major changes to the way the application reads and handles data. The application was reading large amounts of data per request - this pretty much caused the server to overload and hang.